# Unblocking a UDP thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have this runnable receiver which I want to stop. but as it is a constantly receiving socket it's thread is in blocking mode.

I found that I had to stop the socket from outside the thread itself, using socket.close()

So i defined a public static socket. (which itself is bad, i guess?) then i start new threads and try stopping them with this code, (have not changed anything)

```
public static DatagramSocket socket;
```

Starting each thread seperatly works fine. but as the socket now is global, I can't stop them individually. How do I make the socket var global but individual? Or what do I need to make this possible?

```
 public void startSls () throws SocketException{
        try{
            socket = new DatagramSocket(parseInt(port));
        }catch (SocketException e) {
            Log.e("CCSstream", e.toString());
        }
        slst = new Thread(new slss(port));
        slst.start();
    }

    public void stopSls(){
        socket.close();
        stopSLS = true;
        slst.interrupt();
        runThreads1 = false;
    }
```

If anything is unclear I can explain.

Thanks

Comment: If you have multiple sockets, you're not going to keep a *single* `Socket` variable. I'd really hope that you'd be familiar with `Lists`, `Maps` and other `Collection`s before you hop into network programming. You know, learn to walk before you run, otherwise you'll fall and smash your face.

Comment: thats just what i was asking. I'm a bit new to java, so takes a bit getting used to that everything can be stored in maps. have  my user objects stored in maps where the threads are under the user class. so not totally unfamiliar. now I just have to get the user class to list the separate sockets as you said.

Comment: @Kayaman , also asked in a comment here the other day how I could store variables like etc socket to make them act like "dynamic" or what it is called here, and some people said they could not be treated like that in any way. But if lists are the way to go there, i'll try it out :)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by dynamic. You can store any `Object` in a `Map` or other collection, so there are no limitations. A `Map` would allow you to access each `Socket` based on a key such as endpoint name, IP address or whatever you use to distinguish one connection from another.

Comment: You can declare a static map of sockets, with names or numbers as keys and then get /stop necessary socket

Comment: I don't know what the guy ment by dynamic. I said I needed this 
`String astring_+i = "Someinfo " + i's info;` and he said dynamic variables was not possible. 

I have created userobjects in maps for handling the individual threads and socket connections. that is not the problem(or it was not). problem is suddenly I have to have the socket variable outside my thread because it's in blocking mode. so you mean I create a map and on the creation of the user object I add a socket to the map with a id to the user object?

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev Thanks I will give it a shot!

Comment: @KristianMartinsen What he meant was: You cannot declare variables with "dynamic" names. Like `String astring_+i ` where i would be an int variable and the name constructed at runtime. That won't compile. Varnames have to be constant literals at compiletime.

Comment: I've added the function which adds the socket to a map, but does not seem to work, says i'm trying to receive from null and crashes. do I have to initiate the socket somehow? I add it like this: 
       `DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(parseInt(port));
        userSockets.put(port, socket);` and try to get packet like this inside the thread `userSockets.get(data).receive(packet);`

Comment: Your key in the map is the port. If you lookup with data, then "data" has to contain a port number that you added to the map beforehand.

Comment: @Fildor That is correct! nice, now it works well. Though all my catche's are gone (havent removed them, just not working). Seems I can create new threads forever without them saying adr in use or anything. which happend once I clicked before, making threads automaticly stop. but at least one step closer. Thanks for your help people :)

Comment: does not work well after all. it throws socket exception every time it is stopped and started again. which never happend before either. one step forward and two back it seems.

Comment: Found the problem, I can't close and open on the same port.